# Can't add html inside already added html, jquery append()

Tags: jquery, append

i am trying to add html with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) 
inside already added html, but it won't work...
If the html is already there (if i did not add some) then i can add some inside it, but if i add the html and try to add some html inside the added html, then it won't work, and i don't get it...
Hope someone can help me with this problem.
Thanks.
Here is my code

```
<div class="add_episodes">
    <div class="season_episode">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="file" name="episode_image">
        <div class="subtitle_out"></div>
        <div class="btn-addsubtitle">add subtitle</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-addepisode">add episode</button>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 1;

  $("#btn-addepisode").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".add_episodes").append('<div class="add_episode_out"><div class="season_episode"><input type="text" placeholder="Episode titel"><input type="text" placeholder="Indtast filnavn på episoden f.eks. orphan_black"><input class="fileextension_movie_season" type="text" placeholder=".mp4" disabled><input type="file" name="episode_image"><div class="subtitle_out"></div><div class="btn-addsubtitle">add subtitle</div><i class="fa fa-trash delete-episode"></i></div></div>');
    counter = counter + 1;
    initRemove();
  });

  var initRemove = function() {
    $(".delete-episode").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.add_episode_out').find(".season_episode").remove();
      counter = counter - 1;
      if(counter < 1) {
        counter = 1;
      }
    });
  }

});

$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 1;

  $(".btn-addsubtitle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.season_episode').find(".subtitle_out").append('<div class="add_subtitle_out"><div class="add_subtitle"><input type="text" placeholder="Undertekstsprog"><i class="fa fa-trash delete-subtitle"></i><h5>Vælg undertekstfil (filtype .vtt)</h5><input type="file"></div></div>');
    counter = counter + 1;
    initRemove();
  });

  var initRemove = function() {
    $(".delete-subtitle").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.add_subtitle_out').find(".add_subtitle").remove();
      counter = counter - 1;
      if(counter < 1) {
        counter = 1;
      }
    });
  }

});
```

[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/MwQYex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use delegated event by changing:

```
$(".btn-addsubtitle").click(function(e) {
```

To:

```
$('.add_episodes').on('click', '.btn-addsubtitle', function(e) {
```

That's how you attach event handlers to elements that are added to the DOM after DOM ready.

[**.live() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> $( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
>   $( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>   **$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );     // jQuery 1.7+**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6v85w6a6/)

[And the code can be cleaned up a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6v85w6a6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you bind the click event to the element on `document.ready` but your new element is created after this. You have to rebind the click event to the newly created element, or better yet, just call a function from the button via `onclick`.

Comment: I agree that this is at least part of the problem.  I think krunos is thinking these two functions will happen in sequence, with the second one firing off after the first one is done.

Comment: so what you mean is I should make a function like so $(document).ready(function add_subtitle() and then call it with onclick="add_subtitle()" ?

Comment: you dont need to do on `document.ready` since when you click on the button, document would have already loaded. Here is a jsbin example of what I'm talking about: https://jsbin.com/lemayipaha/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your code is running on document ready. Instead use:

```
$('body').on("click", '.btn-addsubtitle', function(){
alert("hi");
});
```

This should run *after * the element is created